# Duplicar campos com MultipleInput Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, multiple

Tenho um formulário que haverá necessidade de duplicidade. Trata-se de um formulário acadêmico.

Nesse formulário, contém os seguintes atributos, segundo o meu *model*:

```
class Academico extends \app\models\MainModel
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'academico';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['member_id', 'instituicao', 'data_inicio', 'data_termino', 'cidade', 'estado', 'tipo'], 'required'],
        [['member_id', 'data_inicio', 'data_termino'], 'integer'],
        [['instituicao', 'cidade', 'estado', 'serie', 'curso', 'tipo'], 'string', 'max' => 191],
        [['member_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Usuario::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['member_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'member_id' => 'Member ID',
        'instituicao' => 'Instituicao',
        'data_inicio' => 'Data Inicio',
        'data_termino' => 'Data Termino',
        'cidade' => 'Cidade',
        'estado' => 'Estado',
        'serie' => 'Serie',
        'curso' => 'Curso',
        'tipo' => 'Tipo',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getMember()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Usuario::className(), ['id' => 'member_id']);
}
```

}

Na minha view, os atributos que carrego são: 'instituicao', 'data_inicio', 'data_termino', 'cidade', 'estado'.

Preciso duplicar todos esses atributos sem ter que ir adicionando um a um, como está na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha view: `

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
    ['id'=>'form-academico']
); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'instituicao')->widget(MultipleInput::className(['cloneButton' => true,])); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'data_inicio')->widget(MultipleInput::className()); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'data_fim')->widget(MultipleInput::className()); ?>
    </div
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer de diversas maneiras, a maior parte delas envolve Javascript.

Com o uso do Select2 (https://select2.org/) você pode criar um taginput, e no backend separar os dados enviados pelo usuário criando múltiplos registros em banco.

Caso, cada linha deva ser um registro, o ideal seria primeiro ter somente um botão de (+), que deixaria menos confusa a interface do usuário, e com o Javascript, duplicar a linha.

Você vai ter que alterar o name dos campos (via javascript) caso seja adicionada mais de uma linha, para que seja enviado um array de objetos, por exemplo:

Se o seu $model::formName() for 'Lorem'
O nome da primeira linha seria Item[0][Lorem][instituicao], Item[0][Lorem][data_inicio], da segunda seria Item[1][Lorem][instituicao], Item[1][Lorem][data_inicio],
no backend para salvar você faria um

```
<?php
  foreach (\Yii::$app->request->post('Item') as $item) {
    $md = new Lorem();
    $md->import($item);
    $md->save();
  }
```